# Issue with htaccess 301 redirects on destination domain when using DNS pointing

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I developed a new WordPress website at www-newdomain-com

(Sorry, using dashes instead of dots in the domain names as i cant post more than 2 links here without a reputation score of 10?..)

The old website at www-olddomain-com was prematurely redirected via DNS (@A records, www records) to www-newdomain-com. I therefore don't have access to a hosting container to create an htaccess file on www-olddomain-com to 301 redirect all the old pages to their new locations. I also have a parked domain setup for www-olddomain-com under www-newdomain-com - it's not an ideal situation, but i'm stuck :-)

The url page names are also completely different on both domains.
WordPress also stores the site address www-newdomain-com in the database and basically hard codes it everywhere.

Wordpress htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Question:
How do I create 301 redirects in htaccess on newdomain in this above scenario?

If I use the following:

```
Redirect 301 /blog http://www.newdomain.com/articles
```

then it works initially, but as soon as I click any working link on www-newdomain-com thereafter, I receive a 500 internal server error.

If I use the following:

```
Redirect 301 /blog /articles
```

then it also works, but it displays the following in the address bar: olddomain-com/articles instead of www-newdomain-com/articles

I also have many of these: www-olddomain-com/blog/?cat=136
If I use:

```
Redirect 301 /blog/ /articles
```

then it loads the new domain 404 page and the address bar displays: http://olddomain-com/articles/?cat=136

I'm in the dark on this one and dont have any experience with htaccess other than the very basics. Any advice will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure you update the wordpress domain configuration to `www-newdomain-com` (go to `/wp-admin/options-general.php` to change it), otherwise it will rewrite every link to `olddomain-com` and mess up with your `.htaccess` rules.

This is why everything points back to `olddomain-com` for now.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Could you please direct me to line number in the file where this must be changed? I'm assuming that this is a "hack" since the SIte URL and WP URL for www-newdomain-com are already stored in the WP database?  Glad to be learning something new :-)

Comment: It's not a line to change, the website domain is stored in the database. If you can access the wordpress admin, then just go to the *URL*  `http://www-newdomain-com/wp-admin/options-general.php` and simply change it there. They are indeed stored in the DB but the old one is currently stored.